# Reactjs changes last three characters of a string automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I am calling an API that should simply return a String (for example 8332912813407677256), and when I enter the get request into the browser, I do get the expected response. However, when sending this request through JavaScript I received 8332912813407677000 as my response.
Here is my code:

```
    sendDateFilterRequest = async () => {
        await fetch(some-request)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ result: data })
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(console.log);
    };
```

The console prints out 8332912813407677000.
Additionally, I have also tried to change the return type to long(the api is written in java), but the last 3 digits are also turned to 0.
Can someone help explain why is this happening?

Comment: javascript numbers have limited precision. You must make sure this stays as a string and is never converted to a number.

Comment: You need to change the API to return the value as a string, not a number. Or, if it only returns the string then don't apply  `.json()` to it.